# How to preserve space in jsx?

Tags: reactjs

This is my jsx

```
   return (
      <div className={styles.message}>
        Today is <span className={styles.date}>
          23 Mar 2017
        </span>.
      </div>
    );
```

You can see there is a space between the word `is` and the `span` tag

However when the page is rendered, the space is removed

[image]

I can insert a `&nbsp;` to create a space i.e.

```
return (
  <div className={styles.message}>
    Today is&nbsp;<span className={styles.date}>
      23 Mar 2017
    </span>.
  </div>
);
```

[image]

But is it the proper solution in jsx? It looks a bit ugly to have `&nbsp;` all over the place.

Comment: How does the actual rendered markup look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting correct output by running following

```
   return (
      <div className="test1">
        Today is <span className="test2">
          23 Mar 2017
        </span>.
      </div>

    );


Today is 23 Mar 2017.
```

As I do not have `{styles}` class so I am using some random name.It seems there is some problem with `{styles}`.
Also you can use `mark` in place of `span`

```
 "<mark className="mark-blue">{data}</mark>"
```

Comment: The `mark` element is a way to highlight (black text on yellow background) and should not be used in this case to color a text, a `span` is absolute perfect